# Reading from a file with Python

Tags: python, file, encoding

For quite a while I have been trying to make a quiz game, that will read questions and answers from a text file and display them on a screen. I used the following function:

```
def start_quiz() :
    text_file = open("quiz_python.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
    for lines in text_file :
        print(lines)
```

I make a .txt file through a standart Notepad word processor and save the file (in the same directory) with an "Utf-8" encoding. However, when I launch the program, it crashes at the very beginning. And what is more suprising, that when I run that program with F5 in IDLE, it works perfectly! At that moment I don't know what to think about all this, because it's quite strange. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Victor.

Comment: Print the stacktrace of the crash. If you don't print the stacktrace or the error message, I can't help you.

Comment: Just note that the python interpreter will assume ASCII if you don't say anything, that means that if you use a non-ASCII character on your script, you can get some errors (not only on the file you are loading)

Answer (score -1):

You didnt say which version of python. Im using 2.x

I think its because you are using the encoding line.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Dec  6 2014, 13:17:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def start_quiz() :
...     text_file = open("quiz_python.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
...     for lines in text_file :
...         print(lines)
... 
>>> start_quiz()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in start_quiz
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>>> def start_quiz() :
...     text_file = open("quiz_python.txt", "r")
...     for lines in text_file :
...         print(lines)
... 
>>> start_quiz()
stuff in a file
>>>
```

I personally use [with open](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) when dealing with files.

```
>>> with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
```

If you need to encode; read all or each line to a variable str and run `str.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')` on it.